# Heroku Scheduler delays several seconds when running a worker app?

Tags: python, heroku, scheduled-tasks

I currently have a Python worker app hosted on Heroku, using the add-on Scheduler. I have the app set to trigger at 5:00am UTC time, but it takes anywhere from 10-20 seconds before the app actually triggers. This is a huge problem for me because I need my app to execute as close to the start time as possible.

As you can see from the attached log statement, the Python app doesn't start running till nearly 18 seconds past the scheduled time.

```
2015-01-23T05:00:18.395694+00:00 app[scheduler.9077]: 2015-01-23 05:00:18 [ MainThread ] [ INFO ] : -------- NEW LOG BLOCK ---------------'
```

I've looked into some latency issues with Heroku, and found some stuff regarding idling dynos and using New Relic to ping these dynos to keep them from idling but those were most focus towards web applications. Or is the same thing happening here? How would I even use New Relic to ping a worker (an application that doesn't have a reachable web address)?

This is really frustrating as it doesn't happen with cron.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get to-the-millisecond precision with the Heroku scheduler -- that's simply not how it works. The scheduler is a 'loose' replacement for cron, but shouldn't be counted on for that level of precision.

If you *need* that much control over timing you'll need to run a worker process -- this way you'll have a dedicated, long-running process that can fire off requests at the exact time you need (without relying on Heroku's API timing stuff).

Answer (score 0):

This is the response I received from the Heroku support team:

> Hi, Our scheduler is a best-effort service, which means it can be
>   delayed by a few seconds, or miss some runs. If your app relies on
>   very accurate scheduled processes, our recommendation is to use a
>   custom clock process. Please let us know if you have any further
>   question. Thanks, Damien

So... my solution. I simply followed this guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python

So I then added a clock process to my Dyno by doing:

`heroku ps:scale clock=1`

I added the following to my procfile:

```
clock: python clock.py
```

I installed the pip requirement (and put it in my requirements.txt):

```
apscheduler==3.0.1
```

And in `clock.py`:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('main')

from main import main
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()

# Executes every night at 5:00am UTC time | 12:00am (midnight) Winston-Salem, NC time
@sched.scheduled_job('cron', hour=5)
def scheduled_job():
    main()

sched.start()
```

I then committed all of it back to Heroku, and it works great. No delay anymore!